# Finish Activity after timeout if user don't touch screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity. All I want is if user don't touch screen, after a TIMEOUT, this activity will automatically finish(). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use `onTouchListener` on your root layout and if there is no touch event `finish` the `Activity`

Comment: have you tried any thing then post it

Comment: see Activity.onUserInteraction method

Comment: yes, you can set timer. Set your time in timer.When timer complete then finish your activity.

Comment: The problem i have got is how to reset timeout when user retouch screen

Comment: use Handler.removeMessages or Handler.removeCallbacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //TODO: Do something every second
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            finish();
            //YourActivity.finish();  outside the actvitiy

        }
    }.start();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

So basically you start a countDown timer and than wait for it to get completed. Once completed, call finish on the activity. 
If in between the user touches the screen, you cancel the timer and start it again.

Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: What if we have some input through keyboard ? It doesn't count the input from keyboard and kills the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Look for how to wait/sleep in Android, examples:

[wait for 3 seconds or user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791307/wait-for-3-seconds-or-user-click)

[Wait a time - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765034/wait-a-time-android)

[How to "wait" a Thread in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151566/how-to-wait-a-thread-in-android)

And when the wait/sleep ends just call the finish() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Activity:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {

         finish();
         //YourActivity.finish();  outside the actvitiy


     }
  }.start();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score -1):

use this :

```
int time =0;
```

then add onTouchListener for your root layout and update time value like this :

```
time = 0;
```

and use the handler for count like this :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    time++;
    if(time>=10000){
            finish();
     }  
    }
    }, 1000);
```

it is clear i set finish time for 10 second.

Comment: It will continue after the activity have been closed